# Get Sitefinitys Generated Password Reset URL

Tags: sitefinity

I am trying to get the URL from the password reset which I receive via email of the sitefinity frontend login.

I need to send the URL with the username which is enterd in the form to a server to send the email.

I already tried to override the SendResetPasswordEmail of the LoginFormModel but that only gives me the URL where the reset is located at. (localhost/login/resetpassword)

It looks like the URL is generated in the method SendRecoveryPasswordMail of the Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.UserManager which is not overridable.

Is there a way to get the generated recovery URL to use it in a custom method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the URL of the reset password page, I guess your issue is getting the proper query string to pass to that page.

Looking at the source code with JustDecompile, the query string is made up of this:

?vk=userValidationKeyEncoded&cp=pr

The cp=pr seems to be hardcoded, so we leave it as is, the question is how the userValidationKeyEncoded is made.

Again, looking in the code, it is this line:

```
 string userValidationKeyEncoded = UserManager.GetUserValidationKeyEncoded(userByEmail);
```

And finally:

```
private static string GetUserValidationKeyEncoded(User user)
{
   object[] providerName = new object[] { user.ProviderName, ',', user.Id, ',', DateTime.UtcNow };
   string str = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", providerName);
   return SecurityManager.EncryptData(str).UrlEncode();
}
```

You can use the above code to manually generate the validationKey.